# why does mnv.riptano.com now require authentication

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax

I am using datastax enterprise and 3.1.4 and the bulkloader. I was getting the cassandra-all:1.2.10.1, cassandra-thrift, cassandra-clientutil and the hadoop jars from http://mvn.riptano.com/content/repositories/releases, but now I am getting a connection refused error. Sometime since 11/25/2013 the mvn.riptano.com repo has changed to require authenticaion and I am not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

That repository is not intended for public consumption, it is used by the development team.

Thanks,
Sven

Comment: Where am I able to get the datastax modified jars then?

Comment: All of the necessary jars come as part of the DataStax Enterprise (DSE) install.